# Remove animations for d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want to have only a default arrangement, and then I only want when dragging a bubble, without affecting the others bubbles:

[image]

Probably the magic is in `tick` event handler:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
       .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
       .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
       .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});
```

How can be this function changed not to animate the other nodes/links, just change the position of the node that is dragged?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/blt909/aVhd8/20/)

Comment: It sounds like you want a [static force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139) plus drag.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Exaclty, and how can I add drag feature?

Comment: `.call(force.drag)` on the circles.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff It doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/aVhd8/60/

Comment: Right, more difficult in this case because you don't have a tick event handler, which would take care of the dragging. You'll have to use the drag behaviour instead -- http://jsfiddle.net/aVhd8/62/ (proof of concept without link dragging).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Hmm... I'm not the best at d3. Can you help by adding moving the links as well...?

Comment: One approach (not the best or most efficient!) is to filter the links to get the ones to be updated http://jsfiddle.net/aVhd8/66/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This is good, post an answer and later you may optimize the things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force layout comes with its own implementation of the drag behaviour, but this only works if you're handling the `tick` events (which you're not doing in this case). So you'll have to use the drag behaviour yourself, which makes things a bit more complex:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", dragged);
svg.selectAll("circle").call(drag);
function dragged(d) {
  svg.selectAll("line")
    .filter(function(e) { return e.source.x == d.x && e.source.y == d.y; })
    .attr("x1", function(e) { return e.source.x = d3.event.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(e) { return e.source.y = d3.event.y; });
  svg.selectAll("line")
    .filter(function(e) { return e.target.x == d.x && e.target.y == d.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(e) { return e.target.x = d3.event.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(e) { return e.target.y = d3.event.y; });

  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}
```

This identifies the links connected to the dragged node by checking the source/target coordinates for each link. This is quite inefficient and not the best way of doing things.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aVhd8/66/).

Comment: Improvement: `e.target.x == d.x && e.target.y == d.y` can be reduced to `e.target === d`, same for `e.source`.